# Canadian refusal 11 years ago

Tags: visa-refusals

I had a candaian refusal 11 years ago and I cannot accurately remember the reason why, I think it had to do with my length of stay and insufficient travel information - subsequent to that I have had 1x Australian business, 2 schengen and 2x 5year UK business Visa's granted without mentioning the refusal and never been asked at entry. I never thought it to be a huge deal until now.
Now I am about to apply for a tier 2 5 year visa with my company for the UK and don't know how to handle that question. Answer yes and be guilty of deceit the other times and not answer yes and hope it does not get checked and if it does get banned. Surely I would have been denied the UK Business VISA's if that had come up on their system?
I've dug myself a hole

Comment: To be clear, did not get your previous visas "without mentioning the refusal" because they never asked, or because they asked but you lied?

Comment: although whatever the answer is to the above question, nobody here is going to advise you to lie on a new application.

Comment: I am not suggesting anyone should suggest I lie - the question is why would my Canada refusal 11 yrs ago not have been a reason to be denied my subsequent UK ViSA's if they all share that information.

Comment: That's why I'm asking if you didn't tell them about the refusal *because they didn't ask* or *because you lied when they asked*. One visa refusal doesn't mean you can't get another visa in future, and depending on the reason for the refusal it might not even affect your future visa chances at all. It's only if you *claimed to have never been refused a visa* that them discovering you were once refused a visa might be expected to lead to an automatic refusal.

Comment: @user56513 "let your conscience guide you" is a very strange thing to find in a comment that clearly advocates submitting false information.

Comment: @user56513 you've more than given your opinion, you've given advice that could potentially damage OP's future travel prospects in exactly the way they're trying to avoid, and apparently somehow believe you're taking the moral highground in doing so.

Comment: @ChrisH That’s your opinion. I see no upside to bringing up an old transgression I **mistakenly committed**. None at all. Especially when revealing it can get me hammered. Many people have gotten hammered for revealing a previous discrepancy however innocuous. You’re not going to change my mind on this, thank you.